# Failed to restore mysql database with zmanda

Tags: mysql, backup, restore

I want to setup a slave from my backup version of mysql using zmanda (it's a full backup). 
I've followed [this guide](http://kb.zmanda.com/article.php?id=116).

Result of `mysql-zrm-reporter`

```
          backup_set  backup_date                  backup_level  backup_status         backup_type       comment
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               6.248  Sun 22 Jul 2012 02:15:15                0  Backup succeeded      regular           ----
                      PM ICT
```

What I grant for backup user:

```
Grants for backup@192.168.6.38: GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, LOCK TABLES, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'backup'@'192.168.6.38' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '****************' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

When run `mysql-zrm --action restore --backup-set 6.38 --source-directory /data/var/lib/mysql-zrm/6.38/20120722141515/`, I got:

```
restore:INFO: ZRM for MySQL Community Edition - version 2.2.0
6.38:restore:INFO: The quick backup-type is supported only for snapshot backups. Setting backup-type to 'regular'
6.38:restore:INFO: Mail address: sysadmin@mycompany.vn is ok
6.38:restore:INFO: ZRM Temporary configuration file = /etc/mysql-zrm/6.38/tmpRPQbB.conf
6.38:restore:INFO: {
6.38:restore:INFO:      verbose=1
6.38:restore:INFO:      encrypt-plugin=/usr/share/mysql-zrm/plugins/encrypt.pl
6.38:restore:INFO:      retention-policy=10W
6.38:restore:INFO:      mysql-binpath=/usr/bin
6.38:restore:INFO:      all-databases=1
6.38:restore:INFO:      default-character-set=latin1
6.38:restore:INFO:      destination=/data/var/lib/mysql-zrm
6.38:restore:INFO:      decrypt-option=-d
6.38:restore:INFO:      source-directory=/data/var/lib/mysql-zrm/6.38/20120722141515/
6.38:restore:INFO:      routines=1
6.38:restore:INFO:      password=******
6.38:restore:INFO:      backup-mode=logical
6.38:restore:INFO:      backup-type=regular
6.38:restore:INFO:      compress-plugin=/usr/bin/gzip
6.38:restore:INFO:      user=backup
6.38:restore:INFO:      copy-plugin=/usr/share/mysql-zrm/plugins/ssh-copy.pl
6.38:restore:INFO:      backup-level=0
6.38:restore:INFO:      replication=1
6.38:restore:INFO:      encrypt=/usr/share/mysql-zrm/plugins/encrypt.pl
6.38:restore:INFO:      mailto=sysadmin@mycompany.com
6.38:restore:INFO:      html-reports=backup-status-info
6.38:restore:INFO:      port=3306
6.38:restore:INFO:      ssh-user=mysql
6.38:restore:INFO:      host=192.168.6.38
6.38:restore:INFO:      single-transaction=1
6.38:restore:INFO:      mail-policy=only-on-error
6.38:restore:INFO:      html-report-directory=/var/www/mysql-zrm/reports/
6.38:restore:INFO:      exclude-pattern=performance_schema
6.38:restore:INFO:      compress=/usr/bin/gzip
6.38:restore:INFO:      mysql-binlog-path=/data/var/log/mysql
6.38:restore:INFO: }
6.38:restore:INFO: Getting mysql variables
6.38:restore:INFO: "/usr/bin"/mysqladmin --user="backup" --password="*****" --host="192.168.6.38" --port="3306" variables
6.38:restore:INFO: datadir is /data/var/lib/mysql2/
6.38:restore:INFO: mysql_version is 5.5.25-cll
6.38:restore:INFO: InnoDB data file are /data/var/lib/mysql2/ibdata1
6.38:restore:INFO: InnoDB log dir is /data/var/lib/mysql2/.
6.38:restore:INFO: Command used is 'cat "/data/var/lib/mysql-zrm/6.38/20120722141515/backup-data"  | "/usr/share/mysql-zrm/plugins/encrypt.pl" -d |  "/usr/bin
/gzip" -d  | tar  --same-owner -xpsC  "/data/var/lib/mysql-zrm/6.38/20120722141515/"  2>/tmp/CnVB7wl750'
6.38:restore:INFO: Checking if this is a replication slave using command
6.38:restore:INFO: "/usr/bin"/mysql --user="backup" --password="*****" --host="192.168.6.38" --port="3306" -e "show slave status"
6.38:restore:INFO: This is not a replication slave or we do not have appropriate access rights. Replication data if any has not been backed up.
6.38:restore:INFO:  Ignoring the --replication option
6.38:restore:INFO: Executing pre-restore-plugin
6.38:restore:INFO: restoring using command "/usr/bin"/mysql --user="backup" --password="*****" --host="192.168.6.38" --port="3306" -e "set character_set_clien
t=utf8;set character_set_connection=utf8;set character_set_database=utf8;set character_set_results=utf8;set character_set_server=utf8;source /tmp/NWxPqSUUzb;"
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 2630 in file: '/tmp/NWxPqSUUzb': Access denied for user 'backup'@'192.168.6.38' to database 'BookingOnline'
6.38:restore:ERROR: Restore from logical backup failed
6.38:restore:INFO: Removing all of the uncompressed/unencrypted data
6.38:restore:INFO: Executing post-restore-plugin
6.38:restore:ERROR: Restore failed
```

As you can see, zmanda complain that access denied for user 'backup'@'192.168.6.38', but If I log in with this user, I can select, update... in database BookingOnline without problem? So what I miss here? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restore user needs more permissions then the backup user. Is this setup correctly for you?

From the [docs](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/Pre-Installation#MySQL_Backup_User)

```
Minimal set of MySQL privileges that MySQL users should have to do backups and recovery are:
backup user 
LOCK TABLES, SELECT, FILE, RELOAD, SUPER, SHOW VIEW*
restore user 
CREATE, DROP, INDEX, SHUTDOWN, INSERT, ALTER, SUPER, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW*
```